# Legendary/Rare Weapon/Outfit Recipe(s)

Tags: fallout-shelter

My dwellers came back from the wasteland with Legendary/Rare Weapon/Outfit Recipe(s) which I cannot access at the moment as I cannot upgrade my Weapon/Outfit Workshop yet.

My question is, are those recipes simply gone after I Collect them or will I get access to them one day after I upgrade my workshops?

Comment: I have just reached 45 dwellers and upgraded weapon workshop and able to craft Rare weapons. Confirmed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the rooms are built/upgraded the recipes you already collected will be available for unlocking.

They are not lost.

Comment: Oh, you have to upgrade the rooms. That answers the question I was about to ask about where my blueprints had disappeared to.